# PATH for PHP "Command Not Found"

Tags: php, macos, path

Forgive me for my ignorance here: I am coding in Symfony2 and I am trying to use the app/console commands to speed up development.

In any case I am using XAMPP for my local server and I am needing to specify where php is installed in my PATH to use app/console.

Here is what my PATH looks like inside of my .bash_profile:

```
/opt/subversion/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php:/usr/local/git/binalias
```

But when I run php -v I get:

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

When I try and run: php ./app/console from inside of my symfony root, I get:

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

If I run:

```
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php -v
```

I get:

```
PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2013 08:28:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Why is my PATH not working when I run, php ./app/console from inside of my Symfony directory.

Any assistance would be GREATLY welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is wrong:

```
/opt/subversion/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php:/usr/local/git/binalias
```

This part:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php
```

Should be:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```